# Shift and Clock Matrices as a Basis for $SU(N)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

[Zachos, Fairlie & Fletcher](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(89)91057-5) introduce the $N\times N$ unitary shift and clock matrices $$\begin{align}
g &= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots& 0\\
    0 & \omega & 0 & \dots& 0\\
    0 & 0 & \omega^2 & \dots& 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \omega^{N-1}
    \end{pmatrix}
&
h &= \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots& 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots& 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots& 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$ with $\omega=\exp[\frac{4\pi i}{N}]$ for $N$ odd, and $$\begin{align}
g &= \sqrt{\omega}\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots& 0\\
    0 & \omega & 0 & \dots& 0\\
    0 & 0 & \omega^2 & \dots& 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \omega^{N-1}
    \end{pmatrix}
&
h &= \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots& 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots& 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots& 1\\
    -1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \label{shiftnclock}
\end{align}$$ with $\omega=\exp[\frac{2\pi i}{N}]$ for $N$ even as a basis for $SU(N)$, a unitary generalization of the Pauli matrices. From these matrices, they build the following generators $$J_{\vec{m}}=\omega^{\frac{m_1m_2}{2}}g^{m_1}h^{m_2}$$ labeled by two-vectors on the integer lattice, and show that they suffice to span the SU(N) algebra $$[J_{\vec{m}},J_{\vec{n}}]= -2i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{N}(\vec{m}\times \vec{n})\right)\,J_{\vec{m}+\vec{n}}$$ (without the factor of 2 in the argument for the even N case) with trigonometric structure constants.

I automatized the generation of these matrices using Mathematica as I wanted to check some simple cases by myself. The construction for odd N works as expected, and indeed fulfills the given SU(N) algebra, but I encountered problems for the even $N$ case. I am generally confused by this distinction between N odd and N even, and I do not understand the argument that the authors make that the algebra resulting from the set of unitary generators describes the SU(N) algebra for N odd but $SU(\frac{N}{2})$ for N even.

More precisely, they argue that for N even, there are 4 generators ($J_{(0,0)},\;J_{(0,N/2)},\;J_{(N/2,0)},\;J_{(N/2,N/2)}$) that commute with all others in the unit cell and thus decouple into $U(1)$ algebras. The remaining $N^2-4$ generators then span 4 copies of commuting $SU(\frac{N}{2})$ algebras. I tried to see this explicitely for $N=4$, which gives 16 $J$ matrices, each of which $4\times 4$ and that should decompose into 4 copies of an $SU(2)$ algebra. But I ran into some inconsistencies, for example, the $$\begin{equation}J_{(2,2)} = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & -i & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & i\\
    i & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & -i & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$ matrix does NOT commute with all other generators. In fact, I found no generator other than the identity ($J_{(0,0)}$) that commutes with all other $J's$. Thus I do not understand where these four copies appear and exactly which generators belong to each copy.

**My questions:**

1. Why is this distinction necessary? Shouldn't the construction for even N be automatically fulfilled for the even N cases as well, allowing us to only consider one definition of the shift and clock matrices?
2. I have seen several definitions for $\omega$ (with exponent $\frac{4\pi i}{N}$ or $\frac{2\pi i}{N}$) and I am not sure when to use which definition. Also, the exact limits of the unit cell confuse me. Does the unit cell always range from $-\frac{N-1}{2}$ to $\frac{N-1}{2}$ or is it only the upper right quadrant from $0$ to $N-1$ in both directions on the $\mathbf{Z}^2$ lattice?
3. Finally, I would like to understand how the even N case works, because I seem to be missing something. It would be nice to see how it works for the $N=4$ case and see which generators correspond to which copy of the $SU(2)$ algebra.

Comment: Of [possible utility](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528788).

Comment: I have indeed read that follow-up paper, but it did not clarify my questions. Is there some detail I am missing?

Comment: I think the last section of J. Patera and H. Zassenhaus, J. Math. Phys. 29 (1988) 665, gives you a better picture of even N than the paper you are reading. The four generators you are writing down, are, indeed, not in the center of the algebra; they do not even commute with each other. I'm having trouble recalling what we had in mind at the time. The odd N stuff is unimpeachable, but the even N needs a construction I am forgetting at the moment.

Comment: Indeed, the paper by Patera and Zassenhaus did give me some more context at the moment. They also give explicit matrix forms of the generators in the 4-dimensional case. I guess in order to make a one-to-one translation to the notation in your paper I should replace the arbitrary exponent that they have in front of the generators by the components of the vector-index. You see, I am interested in your epxlicit form because it gives rise to those trigonometric structure constants which I am particularly interested in. I will look into it, thank you very much!

Comment: The detail that confused me is that the structure constants indeed vanish for those 4 generators that should build the 4 copies of $U(1)$. It is the l.h.s., i.e. the matrix representation of the generators, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Oops! I am a klutz... after 30 years, I should have confirmed that, indeed, the four generators *do* commute with each other.... $J_{(2,2)}= \sigma_2\otimes \sigma_3$...

Comment: But, by trivial explicit computation you may check $[J_{(2,2)}, J_{(3,0)}]\neq 0\neq     [g^2h^2,g^3]$, so both ways. Sorry to say, P&Z are more reliable.

Comment: The difficulty I have with P&Z is that they simply set the phase factor to zero, thus not yielding the trigonometric structure constants. If one fixes the phase to be $\omega^{\frac{m_1m_2}{2}}$ then one is left with the exact same construction as in your case, so the problem would not really be solved. But, if we choose some other phase, then the structure constants will not have the sine-form, thus not allowing for the straighforward large N limit you analyzed.

Comment: Well, in the infinite limit, N and N/2 are no different...